# Is it possible to run Selenoid as a service on Windows Server 2016

Tags: selenoid

I'm setting up Selenoid Windows Server 2016 for IE and Edge browsers.  I'm not attempting to dockerise the windows images as I doubt I'd get this past our security team.

I've got this running from the command line without any issues, but I have two outstanding questions I cannot find the answer to:

1. In browsers.json is it possible to specify the platform?  I cannot find any documentation on how to add this.  While not strictly necessary, I might also have a version of Chrome on the Windows server as well as in a Linux/Docker/Selenoid instance.
2. Is it possible to run selenoid (and/or the UI) as a windows service?  I suspect I'm going to need to configure the server to autologon after a reboot and run selenoid_windows_amd64.exe so the browsers have access to the desktop but I'm hoping to be wrong ;-)

Note: I will be running Selenoid on linux for all other browsers with GGR linking the two.

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently `browsers.json` does not support platforms.
2. It is possible to run Selenoid as Windows service by adding its binary and checking "Allow desktop access" checkbox. However while running Selenoid as Windows service everything (including browsers) will run in so-called `session 0` where maximum screen resolution is limited (at least a few years ago we tried to do this in Windows 7 and screen resolution limitation was `1024x768` or `1280x1024`, don't remember exactly).